# vue.js and chrome extension, getting data from background script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I have followed an example on how to create a Chrome extension using Vue.js.
[vuejs based extension](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-create-vuejs-based-chrome-extension-645d6fe9bf53)
It is working fine, and now I would like to pass the URL of an actual tab (for instance) from a background script to the popup page.

I placed console.log statements in the onMessage and onClicked events in background.js, but these listeners don't receive anything. The onInstalled listener works.

I am relatively new to Vue.js and browser extensions, so I feel a bit lost.
Can you help me with what's missing or what's wrong in my code?

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Random Quote",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Browser extension that fetch a random quote from zenquotes.io",
    "host_permissions": ["https://zenquotes.io/"],
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/icon-16x16.png",
        "48": "images/icon-48x48.png",
        "192": "images/icon-128x128.png"
      }
    },
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "js/background.js"
    }
  }
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function () {
  console.log("onMessage.addListener");
});

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    console.log("onClicked.addListener");
});

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  console.log('Hello, World!');
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en_US">
  <head>
    <title>Random Quote</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/popup.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="js/popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title text-center">Random Quote</h1>
      <blockquote class="quote-card">
        <p>
          {{ state.quote }}
        </p>
  
        <cite> {{ state.author }} </cite>
      </blockquote>
      <blockquote class="quote-card">
         here show URL of the currect Tab 
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        state: {
          quote: "",
          author: "",
        },
      };
    },
    async created() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("https://zenquotes.io/api/random");
        const data = await response.json();
  
        if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
          this.state.quote = data[0].q; // Extract the quote from the response
          this.state.author = data[0].a;
        } else {
          this.state.quote = "Failed to fetch quote.";
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        this.state.quote = "Error occurred while fetching quote.";
      }
    },
  };
  </script>
```

**popup.js**

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import Popup from "./Popup.vue";

console.log("popup.js - 1");
createApp(Popup).mount("#app");
console.log("popup.js - 2");
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require("laravel-mix");

mix
  .setPublicPath("./")
  .sass("src/sass/popup.scss", "dist/css")
  .js("src/js/popup.js","dist/js")
  .js("src/js/background.js","dist/js")
  .vue()
  .copy("src/images/", "dist/images")
  .options({
    processCssUrls: false,
  });
```

**mix-manifest.json**

```
{
    "/dist/js/popup.js": "/dist/js/popup.js",
    "/dist/js/background.js": "/dist/js/background.js",
    "/dist/css/popup.css": "/dist/css/popup.css",
    "/dist/images/icon-128x128.png": "/dist/images/icon-128x128.png",
    "/dist/images/icon-16x16.png": "/dist/images/icon-16x16.png",
    "/dist/images/icon-48x48-off.png": "/dist/images/icon-48x48-off.png",
    "/dist/images/icon-48x48.png": "/dist/images/icon-48x48.png"
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "randomquote",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --env=production --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",
    "postcss": "^8.4.33",
    "sass": "^1.70.0",
    "sass-loader": "^14.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.4.15",
    "vue-loader": "^17.4.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.16"
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) chrome.action.onClicked won't work because you have default_popup so you can simply do whatever you want in your popup script. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. 2) Use chrome.runtime.sendMessage as explained in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/). 3) Note that depending on what your extension does there may be no need for the background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes, I put a piece of code to popup.js and it is working.
``` 
  chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: false }, function (tabs) {

    let list = document.getElementById("demo");
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; ++i) {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerText = tabs[i].url;

      list.appendChild(li);
    }
  })
```
But is it possible to directly update a vue component variable in popup.vue from popup.js ? For instance to update the 'quote' variable.

Comment: @wOxxOm sorry, still a bit confused, in popup.vue I have  <p> {{ state.quote }} </p>
I have in mind to update state.quota directly from popup.js, something like 
state.quote = tabs[0].url;
just as an example.

Comment: To add: In popup.js, I generate a html content dynamicaly, but I thought to send(or set) an array of urls from popup.js and let a vue component to populate a ui of the list automaticaly.

Comment: If I have in a vue component for instance :         
<li v-for="(url, index) in urls" :key="index">
           {{ url }}
 </li>
I would like to do in popup.js, is just to update the vue variable "urls", which is defined in popup.vue.

Comment: I meant you can do it in popup.vue because it'll be compiled into popup.js in the final extension. If you want to set data from outside the component, make a shared `store`  variable which you'll import in both files and then use as for example `store.quote`. See https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm Why make things complicated when they can be done simply? :-) I am getting data from chrome.history.search api directly in popup.vue. I am just wandering why I have to put the method into mounted(), because created() doesnt work - I dont do anything with DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to move '**chrome.history.search**' into '**popup.vue**'. I can see URLs printed in the console, but when I tried to populate the '**history_items**' property with URLs from the history inside the chrome.history.search context, I received an error indicating that **history_items is undefined**. Outside of this block, I am able to populate this property. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

popup.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      state: {
        quote: "",
        author: "",
      },
      history: [],
      history_items: []
    };
  },
  /*   created(){
    this.fetchHistory()
  }, */
  mounted() {

    //this.save();
    this.fetchHistory();
  },
  methods: {
    save() {
      console.log("--save--");
      this.history_items.push("a1");
    },
    fetchHistory() {
      console.log("--fetchHistory--");
      this.history.push("b1");
      console.log("1-this.history_items->" + this.history_items)
      //here I am ok : 1-this.history_items->
      console.log("--this.history.push-- ok");

      chrome.history.search({ text: "", maxResults: 10 }, function (historyItems) {
        for (let item of historyItems) {
          console.log(item.url);
          console.log("2-this.history_items->" + this.history_items)
          //here I am getting : 2-this.history_items->undefined
          this.history_items.push(item.url);
          //here I got the error :Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')         
        }

      });
    },
  },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).